# How to make retrofit request for Postman url?

Tags: android, odata, retrofit2

I have following url which works in Postman but I need it convert into retrofit request.

```
/api/schooldata/Galleries?$orderby=Date desc&$skip=0&$top=10&$filter=Type eq 'Video'
```

I tried this way

```
 @GET("/Galleries?$orderby=Date desc")
Call<ResponseBody> getPhotoGallery(@Query("top")int top, @Query("skip")int skip, @Query("Type") String _type);
```

It displays all the items which should filter instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues,

You are using the wrong parameter name for `Type` -> `$filter`

Your parameter names are missing the `$`

```
@GET("/Galleries?$orderby=Date desc")
Call<ResponseBody> getPhotoGallery(
    @Query("$skip") int skip, 
    @Query("$top") int top, 
    @Query("$filter") String _type
);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one questions that how can I pass filter option as parameter for example I would like to pass boolean parameter with @Query("$filter") but how can I do that?